# Exit full screen using F11 key and Esc key?

Tags: javascript

Most modern browsers support JavaScript APIs for requesting fullscreen mode by now. By default, a user may always press <kbd>F11</kbd> to view a page in fullscreen mode.

If, however, a developer decides to request fullscreen mode by himself on some JavaScript event, this mode can be exited with both the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> keys.

Note that if users request fullscreen mode with the default key (using <kbd>F11</kbd>), it is (tested on newest versions of Chromium and Firefox) not exitable using the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

It's obvious that this makes user interfaces a little inconsistent. Unfortunately, both of these browsers don't seem to register your EventListeners on <kbd>Esc</kbd> once you're in fullscreen, as that's a good choice security-wise.

Is there any way to use this browser API and still be consistent about how users can leave fullscreen mode, i.e. can I make <kbd>Esc</kbd> exit the browser's <kbd>F11</kbd> fullscreen mode, too?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346855/jquery-how-to-execute-code-when-exiting-fullscreen-mode-with-escape-button

Comment: @Alok That topic is about detection of exit from full-screen mode. This one is about how to exit consistently with `Esc` regardless of how exactly (with `F11` key or via Full Screen API) user has entered full-screen mode.

Comment: This is probably a matter of reporting bugs to corresponding bug trackers: see e.g. Firefox bugs [474070](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=474070) and [794468](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794468).